# Grandient Boosting Regressor : "TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type"

Tags: python, gbm

I am new in python and I am trying to developp a program with Gradient Boosting Regressor.
I have two big sets of data, one training set and one test set in wich I have exactly the same columns. My goal is to predict the SeriousDlqin2yrs column of the test set with the information of the training set.

This is the program I wrote :

```
import numpy as np
import csv as csv
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import ensemble
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor
from sklearn.utils import shuffle

# Load data

csv_file_object = csv.reader(open('cs-training-cleandata2NOLOG.csv', 'rb')) #Load in the training csv file
header = csv_file_object.next() #Skip the fist line as it is a header
train_data=[] #Creat a variable called 'train_data'
for row in csv_file_object: #Skip through each row in the csv file
train_data.append(row[1:]) #adding each row to the data variable
train_data = np.array(train_data) #Then convert from a list to an array

test_file_object = csv.reader(open('cs-test-cleandata2NOLOG.csv', 'rb')) #Load in the test csv file
header = test_file_object.next() #Skip the fist line as it is a header
test_data=[] #Creat a variable called 'test_data'
ids = []
for row in test_file_object: #Skip through each row in the csv file
ids.append(row[0])
test_data.append(row[1:]) #adding each row to the data variable
test_data = np.array(test_data) #Then convert from a list to an array

test_data = np.delete(test_data,[0],1) #remove SeriousDlqin2yrs

print 'Training '
# Fit regression model

clf = GradientBoostingRegressor(n_estimators=1000, min_samples_split=100, learning_rate=0.01)
clf = clf.fit(train_data[0::,1::],train_data[0::,0])

print 'Predicting'

output=clf.predict(test_data)

open_file_object = csv.writer(open("GradientBoostedRegression1.1.csv", "wb"))
open_file_object.writerow(["Id","Probability"])
open_file_object.writerows(zip(ids, output))
```

But when I run the program, python give me this answer :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Paul HONORE\Dropbox\Research Study\Kaggle\Bank\GradientBoostedRegression1.1.py", line 64, in <module>
    clf = clf.fit(train_data[0::,1::],train_data[0::,0])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\gradient_boosting.py", line 1126, in fit
    return super(GradientBoostingRegressor, self).fit(X, y)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\gradient_boosting.py", line 595, in fit
    self.init_.fit(X, y)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\gradient_boosting.py", line 69, in fit
    self.mean = np.mean(y)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 2716, in mean
out=out, keepdims=keepdims)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py", line 62, in _mean
ret = um.add.reduce(arr, axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out, keepdims=keepdims)
TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

I don't know from where it comes, i read lots of paper about this question but never found a solution for this particular problem.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python - "cannot perform reduce with flexible type" when trying to use numpy.mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20061095/python-cannot-perform-reduce-with-flexible-type-when-trying-to-use-numpy-mea)

Comment: It's not the same things, I already read this topic but this is not same problem.

Answer (score 2):

i think the problem will be solved by specifying a type in the array function.
for instance:

```
train_data = np.array(train_data, dtype = 'float_')
```